# Index order of a shuffle dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have two `DataFrame`, namely `A` and `B`. `B`is generated by shuffling rows of `A`. I would like to know each row of `B`, what's the index of the same row in `A`.

Example:

```
A=pd.DataFrame({"a":[1,2,3],"b":[1,2,3],"c":[1,2,3]})
B=pd.DataFrame({"a":[2,3,1],"b":[2,3,1],"c":[2,3,1]})

A
    a   b   c
0   1   1   1
1   2   2   2
2   3   3   3

B
    a   b   c
0   2   2   2
1   3   3   3
2   1   1   1
```

The answer should be `[1,2,0]`, because `B` equals `A.loc[[1,2,0]]`. I am wondering how to do this efficiently since my `A` and `B` is large.

Comment: You could put the index of `A` in a column and shuffle after that.
`A['index_a'] = A.index`

Comment: @Kamil Niski  Actually, the process of generating `B` is unable to reproduce.

Comment: What do you mean? I'm aware that it is random. You want to say that you just have `A` and `B` dataframe and you are not doing shuffling? Only information is `A` and `B`? You cannot add a column before shuffling?

Comment: @Kamil Niski Kind of. `A` and `B` are fetching from two different websites, but not directly generated from each other by my hand. Indeed, they are two same dataset, one with ground true label, the other doesn't. I want to generate the label of `B` by re-ordering the label of `A`. That's why I am doing this to get the row order index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with probable solution using `Dataframe.merge`

```
A=pd.DataFrame({"a":[1,2,3],"b":[1,2,3],"c":[1,2,3]})
B=pd.DataFrame({"a":[2,3,1],"b":[2,3,1],"c":[2,3,1]})

A['index_a'] = A.index
B['index_b'] = B.index

merge_df= pd.merge(A, B, left_on=['a', 'b', 'c'], right_on=['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

Where `merge_df` is

```
   a  b  c  index_a  index_b
0  1  1  1        0        2
1  2  2  2        1        0
2  3  3  3        2        1
```

Now you can reference the rows from `A` or `B` Dataframe

**Example**
You know that row with index `0` at `A` is at index `2` in `B`

> **NOTE** Rows that do not match on neither dataframe will not be shown in `merge_df`

Answer (score 1):

IIUC use [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

```
pd.merge(B.reset_index(), A.reset_index(), 
                      left_on = A.columns.tolist(),
                      right_on = B.columns.tolist()).iloc[:,-1].values

array([1, 2, 0], dtype=int64)
```